# Saving docker container logs with container names instead of container IDs

Tags: docker, logrotate

With the default json-file logging driver, is there a way to log rotate docker container logs with container names, instead of the container IDs?

The container IDs in the log file name look not so readable, which is when i thought of saving the logs with container names instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to configure the engine with log options to include labels in the logs:

```
# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3",
    "labels": "com.docker.stack.namespace,com.docker.swarm.service.name,environment"
  }
}

# docker run --label environment=dev busybox echo hello logs
hello logs
root@vm-11:/etc/docker# docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
9615c898c2d2        busybox             "echo hello logs"   8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 7 seconds ago                       eloquent_germain

# docker logs --details 961
environment=dev hello logs

# more /var/lib/docker/containers/9615c898c2d2aa7439581e08c2e685f154e4bf2bb9fd5ded0c384da3242c6c9e/9615c898c2d2aa7439581e08c2e685f154e4bf2bb9fd5ded0c384da3242c6c9e-json.log
{"log":"hello logs\n","stream":"stdout","attrs":{"environment":"dev"},"time":"2020-09-22T11:12:41.279155826Z"}
```

You need to reload the docker engine after making changes to the daemon.json, and changes only apply to newly created containers. For systemd, reloading is done with `systemctl reload docker`.

To specifically pass the container name, which isn't a label, you can pass a "tag" setting:

```
# docker run --name test-log-opts --log-opt tag="{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}" busybox echo hello log opts
hello log opts

# docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
c201d0a2504a        busybox             "echo hello log opts"   6 seconds ago       Exited (0) 5 seconds ago                       test-log-opts

# docker logs --details c20
tag=test-log-opts%2Fc201d0a2504a hello log opts

# more /var/lib/docker/containers/c201d0a2504addedb2b6785850a83e8931052d0d9778438e9dcc27391f45fec2/c201d0a2504addedb2b6785850a83e8931052d0d9778438e9dcc27391f45fec2-json.log
{"log":"hello log opts\n","stream":"stdout","attrs":{"tag":"test-log-opts/c201d0a2504a"},"time":"2020-09-22T11:15:26.998956544Z"}
```

For more details:

- JSON log driver options: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/#options
- Container logging tags: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/

Comment: Thanks @bmitch for the detailed explanation.